# Android activity abstract method call

Tags: android, abstract-class, android-activity

I have an abstract class called BaseActivity (extends Activity) which has a function

public abstract void onLocationChanged();

All other activities extends this class. When I call BaseActivity's method onLocationChanged() I would expect, that all other classes that implement this method would call their onLocationChanged() method or at least the activity that is currently on top of the stack, but it seem that only one activity calls the method and it is not the one on top of the stack.

Can someone help?

here are relevant parts of my code:

```
abstract class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public static MyLocation location = null;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     if (location == null) {
         location = new MyLocation(this);
     }
 }
 public abstract void onLocationChanged();
}

public class MyLocation {
    BaseActivity parrent;
    public MyLocation(BaseActivity act) {          
        public MyLocation(BaseActivity act) {       
        this.parrent = act;      
    }
   public void refreshMyLocation() {
     /*location get refreshed here*/
     this.parrent.onLocationChanged();
   }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
         BaseActivity.location.refreshMyLocation();
 }

 public void onLocationChanged() {
   /*some stuff*/
 }
}
```

Comment: show some code. Like how you are calling the method.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling on location changed on an instance of base activity not all of them at once. Without your code I don't know which one. But simply declaring a method in a base class does not mean it will be called on every class that implements it.

Comment: I guess the problem i my missunderstaanding of principles. Do you have any idea how to do it diferently? The problem is that i have button "update location" in my app that envokes static method from BaseActivity that gets current location. I want to notify any activity that is on the screen that the location has changed.

Comment: Yeah I think it might be a Java fundamental understanding. But what was suggested above should work - look into a LocalBraodcastManager and using Broadcast Receivers. When the location listener gets a location it can broadcast that in an intent and all your activities can register a receiver in their onResume methods and unregistered them in on Pause.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why do you want to do that. I think you should need a Serivice that implements onLocationChanged and communicates with activities via Handler or BroadcastReceiver.